# HTML doctype, how browser performs on reading doctype

Tags: html, browser, doctype

actually i was thinking how browser performs or knows when it reads an specific doctype and after reading doctype, is there a pattern present or build in the browser or it searches on internet to know how to display ?

Comment: does the local copy gets updated if any changes are there in standard mode in future ?

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the doctype header of an html page

HTML5 looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

HTML4

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"{{dead link|date=May 2017 |bot=Pigsonthewing |fix-attempted=yes }}>
```

there is a wiki on the different doctypes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration

It's up to the browser vendor what doctypes to support. Generally they want to support as many different types to have as broad user base as possible. Which is also where all the trouble come in, since they will have to support 40 years or so of doctypes, there are still some ancient websites out there.

Comment: actually i wasn't able to phrase my question properly. i want to know that how browser works after seeing <!doctype html> or any other version ? Does it have library for it or sees on internet. (i was concerned about loading of website so this question)